# Visual Studio Express 2013 and Silverlight RIA Services development

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-express

I have a project made with Silverlight 5 and RIA Services. It works ok on Visual Studio Professional (2010/2012/2013) and the RIA client code generation is running perfect.

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2013 Express (for Web) to build my project, but the RIA client code generation doest't work and doesn't shows any error message to show me what happened... I checked if the my  in the csproj would have a problem, but it is configured properly.

Somebody knows if there is some workaround get this working? 
Or, if the Express Visual Studio versions' are incompatible with this feature?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Visual Studio Community Edition.  It is more like the Professional Edition and allows for different project types in the same solution.  It may fix your issue.

[Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)

Comment: I cannot use the community version because it's not free for comercial development. Right now, I solved this trouble updating to the new OpenRiaServices project. This new reference generates the client code from templates inside the nuget packages.